# Is it possible for two people to simultaneously gain access on one azure powershell session?

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud

We're using cloud powershell in Azure, is it possible that someone from the company gain access to my session and see in live what I'm typing/executing?

I'm aware that since everything is in the cloud, everyone with the correct permissions can access the data but can anyone also have access to the powershell commands of another session without using the .bash_history file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Azure Cloud Shell is assigned per unique user account and automatically authenticated with each session. It is not possible for any other user to access your cloud shell session live.

You can persist history across different sessions but it cannot be accessed by anyone else unless someone has access to your cloud drive.

The below link will help you understand Azure cloud shell in detail:

https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/01/azure-cloud-shell/